# How to retrieve data from json, loop through it and use it as parameter in router in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a data, which looks like this 
[My data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYii8.png)

At the moment, I I loo through data like this

```
this.arr = Object.keys(data).map(k => data[k].rName);
```

So I get a list of `rNames` and show it in my html with `ngFor`.

```
  <mat-card *ngFor="let room of arr">
    <mat-card-content>

      <h3>Room Number: {{room}}</h3>
      <button (click)="next()">Info</button>

    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
```

Now I would like to make small changes, I want to make an array of rnames and floorfCodes, like this
`[{rname1, floorCode1}, {rname2, floorCode2}]` etc., loop through names and if I click button, pass the floorCode to the next page.

So, my routing-function, will work like this:

```
  next() {
    this.router.navigate(['roomdetail', this.buildingID, this.floor ]);
  }
```

My question is: how could I retrieve data(array of objects) and how could I access it later in buttons, so I could pass the data to the router?

Comment: data is coming via services

Answer (score 0):

You could do a BehaviourSubject:

On your service you would initialize it:

```
export class RoomService {
  _roomBehaviour: BehaviorSubject<RoomResponse>;
  _roomList: RoomResponse;
  construct(){
    this._roomList = new RoomResponse();
    this._roomBehaviour = new BehaviorSubject<RoomResponse>(this._roomList);
    this.updateRoomList();
  }

  getRoomList () {
    return this._roomBehaviour;
  }

  updateRoomList () {
    this.http.get<RoomResponse>(
      'url',
      'headers').subscribe(response => {
        this._roomBehaviour .next(response);
    });
  }
}
```

And instead of

```
this.arr = Object.keys(data).map(k => data[k].rName);
```

You would retrieve your data by making a call to the room service.

```
this.roomService.getRoomList();
```

Since it already retrieve the data once at initialization of the Object it would pass the saved values.